# The issue in the embedded code. Video is not playing on the shared platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, youtube, share, embed

I am developing a video app. I need to play the video when I share a video link to any platform like youtube. Like below:

[image]

But in my case it just displays a description and a thumb image. I have tried with many metatags but it's not working with any. I have tried with the same metatags as youtube but it's not working either.

Can you please help me with this concern?

**Metatags**

```
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="">
    <meta property="og:url" content="">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="">
    <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="">
    <meta property="og:title" content="">
    <meta property="og:description" content="">
    <meta property="og:image" content="">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="">
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    <meta property="og:video:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="" />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="" />
    <meta property="og:video" content="">
    <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="">
    <meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="">
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="">
    <meta property="al:ios:url" content="">
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="">

    <meta name="twitter:site" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:iphone" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:iphone" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:ipad" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:ipad" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:name:googleplay" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:image:width" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:image:height" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:player" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:player:width" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:player:height" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:ipad" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:app:url:googleplay" content="">
```

Comment: Please provide any code you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sBws8MSXN7A" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You have set the URL in the iframe first of all.
And the URL youtube shares is in the format of `https://youtu.be/sBws8MSXN7A` and you have to convert it into `https://www.youtube.com/embed/sBws8MSXN7A`

So use JS to format that